# Laravel - return view in subfolder

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have got following lines:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('main.index');
});
```

**But my view is located in main/sub/index.blade.php**

I tried

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('main.sub.index');
    });
```

also

```
 Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
        return view('main/sub.index');
    });
```

didnt work.

Answer (score 16):

Move the view to:

```
resources/views/main/sub/index.blade.php
```

Then this code will work:

```
Route::get('/dashboard', function () {
    return view('main.sub.index');
});
```

From [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#creating-views):

> Views are stored in the `resources/views` directory. Since this view is stored at `resources/views/greeting.blade.php`, we may return it using the global `view` helper like so:

```
return view('greeting', ['name' => 'James']);
```